# Best practice for throwing exceptions in an utility class

Tags: c#, facebook, exception

I am creating a utility class that will be used in my Facebook application for tasks that are commonly done, such as retrieving a Facebook Page ID from a URL. I am unsure if the below code is the correct way to throw and catch exceptions. Could someone please advise, thanks.

Utility Class:

```
public static class FacebookUtilities
{ 
    public static string GetPageIDFromGraph(string pageUri, string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic result = client.Get(GetPageIDFromUri(pageUri), new { fields = "id" });
            return result.ToString();
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static string GetPageIDFromUri(string pageUri)
    {
        if (pageUri.Contains('/'))
            pageUri = pageUri.Substring(pageUri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if (pageUri.Contains('?'))
            return pageUri.Substring(0, pageUri.IndexOf('?'));
        else
            return pageUri;
    }
}
```

Program class, just testing:
- Note "input" and "output" are just textboxes.

```
    private void btnGetPageID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            output.Text = FacebookUtilities.GetPageIDFromGraph(input.Text, "Some Access Token Goes Here");
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 803)
            {
                output.Text = "This page does not exist";
            }
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 100)
            {
                output.Text = "The request was not supported. The most likely cause for this is supplying an empty page ID.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it correct to simply rethrow the exception from the utility class so that the calling class can catch it and do what needs to be done?

Comment: There is no use in `GetPageIdFromGraph` catching those two exceptions just to rethrow them; other exceptions are not caught here, so they continue to bubble up. Is that what you are asking about? The code in `btnGetPageID_Click` is fine if you want to handle only the two exceptions defined and blow up on everything else.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do nothing with catched exceptions - so dont catch them. There are a lot of discussions about exception handling, but in general you should catch exceptions when you have something to do with them, or at least using finally to clean up resourses.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't handling the exceptions in any way, your code can just be:

```
public static string GetPageIDFromGraph(string pageUri, string accessToken)
{
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    dynamic result = client.Get(GetPageIDFromUri(pageUri), new { fields = "id" });
    return result.ToString();
}
```

You should only catch exceptions when you can meaningfully handle them, and it doesn't look like you can in your `GetPageIDFromGraph` method, so you should just propagate them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - makes perfect sense!